# Click event to open a calendar component

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I have the following code:

```
<p:calendar id="initialDate"
            styleClass="calendar"
            value="#{dashboardMB.initialDate}"
            converter="localDateConverter" />

<p:graphicImage style="position: relative;
                left: 25px;
                top: 4px;
                width: 18px;
                height: 18px;"
                library="img"
                name="ui-icon-calendar.png"
                width="24"
                height="24" />
```

How it would be possible for an onclick event on this `p:graphicImage` open the `p:calendar` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to trigger it from an other element:

```
<p:calendar showOn="both" widgetVar="myWidget" styleClass="mycal">

    </p:calendar>
    <a onclick="PF('myWidget').jqEl.datetimepicker('show');return false;" href="#">open calendar</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't display anything when I click the link. And `return true` also didn't work.

Comment: "ReferenceError: myWidget is not defined"

Comment: Then have you added widgetVar="myWidget" to your p:calendar ?

Comment: Added another calendar and a link almost exactly like your answer: `<p:calendar showOn="both" widgetVar="myWidget"></p:calendar>
 <a onclick="myWidget.jqEl.datetimepicker('show');return false;" href="#">Teste</a>`

Comment: Is there any JS error on page load, because if you declare a widget var it should be made available on your page by primefaces.

Comment: Only a warning about jQuery methods `getUserData()` and `setUserData()`.

Comment: I can't figure out why it's not working for you, what's you primefaces version ? It works for me on 4.0

Comment: I typed myWidget only, instead of PF('myWidget'). Your code is working. :) Thanks